# Calling a public method from another class doesn't respond

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making a game library with C#.

I have a main Form which has a FlowLayoutPanel, which hosts the game library. There is an "add game" method in main Form which adds an item to FlowLayoutPanel, but this method is being called from a second form. But when I'm calling this method from this second form, nothing happens at all, but it works, if called from the main form.

Here's the code:

Here's the add game method in mainForm:

```
    public void addIso()
    {
        PictureBox gameBox = new PictureBox();
        gameBox.ImageLocation = "link here";
        gameBox.Height = 200;
        gameBox.Width = 150;
        gameBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        isoPanel.Controls.Add(gameBox);
    }
```

This method adds a placeholder game to FlowLayoutPanel called isoPanel. Works when called from the same form.

And here's how the method is being called from second form:

```
    private void addGameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow mainForm = new MainWindow();
        mainForm.addIso();
    }
```

When I tried to add simple message box in the method, message box did show, but game wasn't added to FlowLayoutPanel.

Any tips or solutions?

I apologize for my poor english and messy programming terms, I started learning C# a little while ago.

Comment: Without having the code for MainWindow, i'm assuming that it's because you're creating a new instance of MainWindow. Try calling `mainForm.addIso()` to the currently instantiated instance of MainWindow?

Comment: I mean, `this` is a pretty helpful keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can achieve this by using `delegate` and `Delegate`.

**What you are doing wrong here:**

From `addGameButton` click event you are creating a new instance of the mainForm. Which is not the actual main form that you are currently seeing, its a different instance of the mainForm. your code adds the control to the layout just confirm this by calling `mainForm.Show()` this will opens a new form with the control.

**What you can do:**

In such cases, you want to modify the parent control, calling methods in parent class, you need to use delegates by the following way:

Changes needs to apply in the Parent class ie., `MainWindow`.

1. Define a delegate and an event of that delegate type.

   ```
   public delegate void UpdateUiDelegate();
   public event UpdateUiDelegate UpdateUiEvent;
   ```
2. Assign the required method to the Event(better use this in constructor):

   ```
   public MainWindow ()
   {
      UpdateUiEvent+= new UpdateUiDelegate(addIso);
   }
   ```
3. Next work is in the child form ie., `Form2` (use a better name let it be `ImageChildControl`). Create a Delegate there:

   ```
   public Delegate ControlCreator;
   ```
4. Come back to MainWindow, Locate the place where you are calling the Second form, after creating instance of the child form assign the created event to that Delegate of the instance, for that Use the following codes there:

   ```
   ImageChildControl ImageChildControlInstance = new  ImageChildControl();
   ImageChildControlInstance.ControlCreator = UpdateUiEvent;
   ```
5. One more work to do in child form that is; Calling the delegate from the Button click event. ie.,

   ```
   private void addGameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ControlCreator.DynamicInvoke(); 
   }
   ```

   Now you can see your code works as you expected.

Comment: Hey, thanks for explaining what I was doing wrong, now I atleast get what was wrong. Thanks for snippets, but I can't seem to insert "LogoutDelegateEvent += new LogoutDelegateEvent(addIso);" anywhere. It says it doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: I actually tried that, but it still shows "LogoutDelegateEvent does not exist in current context"

Comment: Take a look into the updates `UpdateUiEvent` is your event `LogoutDelegateEvent ` is not in the scenario

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. At first, I didn't notice you edited the post.

Comment: Lol happy to help u

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be recreating the form when you load the second form.
as this does lack a little context.

I suggest you have a main tread which will run the two forms

create a game manager class Ex: GameManager.cs

In the class create a variable for both forms and set them as protected.

in each form send a reference of the gamemanager to it.

which will allow each window to communicate with each other through the manager by provide secure inter communication.

Let me know if you would like some source with this.

[image: Schematic -mspaint]

Comment: instead of calling your main form in program.cs call the game manager class and let it setup both forms and then hand over control to the event system. as you use buttons, etc..